# Why do Buddhists have children?

Tags: theravada, parents

In Buddhism they teach that life is suffering, that it's all about pain (which is true) and that you should try your best to achieve Nirvana and become someone who won't have any more rebirths. This is something that I've learnt since I was young. So I was wondering, if parents love their child, why do they decide to have a child? I mean Buddhist parents. Now think about it. If parents know life is about suffering and pain and it's not the best thing why would they want it for their child? I mean seriously, if they really love their child and they are pure Buddhists, according to Buddhism they should not feel the need to have a child because that will cause the child to experience all the pains, etc. So as a mother or father, who wants their child to be in pain? I just don't understand, correct me if I'm wrong.

I'm a Theravada Buddhist.

Comment: Yes, duplicated question

Comment: x Nova I think the question is very good but please refer to the other one that has more answers.

Comment: A couple deciding not to have children does not prevent any being from being born again.

Comment: I'm not sure this really is a duplicate question. The core of this question is "why have children if life is pain", the core of the other question is "can we stop the cycle of rebirth by not having children"

Comment: Well said @THelper , you understood this :)

Comment: @xNova Would you mind if I edited your question a bit to see if we can get it reopened?

Answer (score 0):

I think you mix up pain with suffering.
Pain is something that happens. Suffering you do to yourself, a [second arrow](http://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/sn/sn36/sn36.006.than.html)

And from what I understand Buddhists view being born human to be lucky, as you get the chance to have influence on your own fate. You can get the chance to hear about and perhaps understand the [Four Noble Truths](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Four_Noble_Truths) and start following the [Eightfold Path](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noble_Eightfold_Path) that leads to an end of suffering (but not pain(1)). And perhaps even an escape to the cycle of rebirth.

So Buddhists don't really have a reason to not have children.

(1)Be happy, you have done the first steps.

Comment: Yes buddhists view being born as a human lucky when compared to be born as other animals. But I believe buddhism prefers not being born in the first place.

Comment: Its only compared to other beings, but buddhism believes that not being born in the first place , but if born then obviously being a human is considered way better than any other creature...re-read my question please :)